# Anonymous users getting login prompt when they filter SharePoint list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-on-prem, login, anonymous-access

Anonymous user are able to view page(sitepage/main.aspx) in sharepoint 2013 on-premise.

(main.aspx contains HTML file, JS file, script editor, list web part called "mydata" with view "myview").

But the problem is as soon anonymous user set the filter for any column, a login prompt is shown. I want to get rid of the login prompt even when filter is applied.

things I tried:

1. Anonymous user enabled at central admin
2. anonymous user enabled at site collection
3. anonymous user has permission for the list/html/images/css/js (and all items that render on main.aspx) etc (by breaking inheritance and grant anonymous access)
4. also anonymous user has access to folder/directory where these images/js etc are stored
5. enabled check-in and publishing
6. all items/assets are published
7. disabled Limited-access user permission lockdown mode  (in site collection features)
8. iisreset

---

**Update 1**: When I see console after "cancel" login prompt I see:

```
http://myurl/_layouts/15/inplview.aspx?List={7798XXXX-6662-43CF-A90E-2A195XXXXXXX}&View={EC8A0306-XXXX-48C8-AA93-6EEF5EEXXXXX}&ViewCount=0&IsXslView=TRUE&IsCSR=TRUE&FilterField1=Sector&FilterValue1=designation
```

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you did not grant API access to your anonymous users; so what you have done is needed, but not yet enough.

You have to uncheck  `Require Use Remote Interface` option from your site collection settings. Do the same thing through Central Administration (*Manage Web Application* -> *Authentication Providers*).

(I do not remember the differences betweeen 2013 and 2016 but it should help you!)